# How to resolve Fragment cannot be converted to Context error?

Tags: android, android-fragments, error-handling

in my fragment below error comes in Android studio.
**error: incompatible types: EmployeeSetaFragment cannot be converted to Context**

how to resolve it?

```
public class EmployeeSetFragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private PoemAdapter adapter;
    private ArrayList<Poem> employeeArrayList;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_people,container,false);

        employeeArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        employeeArrayList.add(new Poem("no 1 ", "mark"));

recyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

            adapter = new PoemAdapter(employeeArrayList);
            RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(EmployeeSetFragment.this);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            return  v;
```

Comment: I strongly feel you will have to do some reading about contexts and android as a whole instead of just making this work, however, that being said you can use getActivity() or even the context of the fragment by doing getContext()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
```

Instead of

```
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(EmployeeSetFragment.this);
```